# Convert a list of strings [ '3', '1', '2' ] to a list of sorted integers [1, 2, 3]

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, integer

I have a list of integers in string representation, similar to the following:

```
L1 = ['11', '10', '13', '12', 
      '15', '14',  '1',  '3', 
       '2',  '5',  '4',  '7', 
       '6', '9', '8']
```

I need to make it a list of integers like:

```
L2 = [11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8]
```

Finally I will sort it like below:

```
L3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] # by L2.sort()
```

Please let me know what is the best way to get from `L1` to `L3`?

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: Not all basic questions are homework. Let the OP indicate if it is homework.

Answer (score 19):

You could do it in one step like this:

```
L3 = sorted(map(int, L1))
```

In more detail, here are the steps:

```
>>> L1 = ['11', '10', '13', '12', '15', '14', '1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8']
>>> L1
['11', '10', '13', '12', '15', '14', '1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8']
>>> map(int, L1)
[11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8]
>>> sorted(_)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>>
```

Comment: I didn't know you can use the underscore like that. Is that interpreter specific? +1

Comment: @Xavier, that's a little convenience thing within the interactive interpreter only.

Comment: Yes `_` only does work in the interpreter this way. The only way I know of to "access" `_` within a script is inside a list comprehension `locals()['_[1]'].__self__` will return the list that is being constructed.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> L1 = ['11', '10', '13', '12', '15', '14', '1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8'] 
>>> L1 = [int(x) for x in L1]
>>> L1
[11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8]
>>> L1.sort()
>>> L1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> L3 = L1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
L3 = sorted(int(x) for x in L1)
```